# OS X 10.9: where are password hashes stored

Tags: macos, security, password

I think on previous versions of OS X, password were stored in the /etc/shadow file.

Nevertheless, this file doesn't appear to exist in the later versions of the operating system - specifically OS X 10.9 which is the first of the non-cat named OS releases.

Does anyone know where the password hashes are stored on OS X Mavericks?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Starting with Lion, OS X introduced a shadow file *per user* that is a plist dictionary that contains password hashes and other GID/UID/kerberos and open directory type keys.

The shadow files are stored on the filesystem at `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users`. They are in [plist format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) so you'll need to use the [plutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html) command to view them or use the defaults command to extract/write specific keys if desired. Only the `root` user has access to the files.

To view the contents of a shadow file for a user:

```
sudo plutil -p /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<username>.plist
```

To get the hash:

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<username>.plist ShadowHashData|tr -dc 0-9a-f|xxd -r -p|plutil -convert xml1 - -o -
```

Where `<username>` in the above examples is the user you're looking for the hash for. You want the `<data>` section that corresponds to the `<key>entropy</key>` key in that plist output.

To continue on to try and crack the password [see this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703020831/http://www.michaelfairley.co/blog/2014/05/18/how-to-extract-os-x-mavericks-password-hash-for-cracking-with-hashcat/).

Comment: This is not working for me: it says that ShadowHashData is not a valid property in <username>.plist...

Comment: @MarkWright what OS X version? Works great for me on 10.11.3. Are you using LDAP for the accounts or is it a local account?

Comment: I am using 10.9 on single user mode.

Comment: What does `sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/${USER}.plist` show for you?

Comment: @MarkWright same happened to me osx:10.10.5 Using that command returns "Domain /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/${USER}.plist does not exist"

Comment: Starting with macOS 10.13, [`/var/db/dslocal/nodes` is unreadable even by the root user when System Integrity Protection is enabled](/q/344117/21748).

Comment: `sudo plutil -p` still seems to work in 10.14, even with SIP enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add to the accepted answer, just in case someone tries to get the password hashes stored on an OS X Server in Open Directory. For network (OD) users you need to

```
sudo mkpassdb -dump
```

which will get you a list of users and their respective slot IDs. Copy the entire slot ID beginning with 0x and issue

```
sudo mkpassdb -dump slot_id_that_you_retrieved
```

You'll see several digest entries, amongst which *cmusaslsecretSMBNT is the NTLM password hash and *cmusaslsecretDIGEST-MD5 is the regular MD5 hash. Do with those what you wish, but I found it easier to submit those to https://hashkiller.co.uk/ntlm-decrypter.aspx which is a free online hash cracking service. It accepts your hash and if not yet in their database will start working on it. Return a week later and it should be cracked. This has been tested on OS X El Capitan and Mac OS Sierra. You may not see digests if some auth methods have been explicitly disabled on your server but they should be there by default.

Answer (score -2):

I looked it up on Google and found this:
http://hackmac.org/forum/topic/2678-ceacking-os-x-mountain-lion-os-x-mavericks-os-x-yosemite-account-password

Comment: The link is broken.  Also note that link-only answers without explanation are frowned upon.