# How to get users hashed password

Tags: macos, password

I am playing about with 'John the ripper' to see how easily my password can be cracked. The only issue i I cannot seem to fin the hashed password.

Things I've tried.

- Reading hash from `/etc/passwd` - Result: No user found
- `sudo dscl . -read /Users/<user>/ | grep GeneratedUID | cut -c15-` `cat /var/db/shadow/hash/<Result From First Command> | cut -c169-216` - Result: directory 'shadow' does not exist
- Some others (forgotten what they were. Had similar issues.

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186893/os-x-10-9-where-are-password-hashes-stored?rq=1) also didn't work for me.

Would like to know where the password hash is for my user so I can test out JTR.
Thanks in advanced.

**Edit:**
When I do `sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/Test.plist ShadowHashData|tr -dc 0-9a-f|xxd -r -p|plutil -convert xml1 - -o -` I get 2 hashes`'zcvUSru/AH3YNusqitC14z8dm8iX9dZTRzKKkv+oMODQQ9CG79yGmsjo8s13UCSIZ6TmE/U2krMC7KzxgafDwVkOq0eJ1F6aYFUBex649rUnj/58jhCp7Lgt5vWYN95SrDQwMKEYkFXkHM/Ieg0GsnCJnZwem4ugfSnU2fKCquE=` and `weXOBzKgCTzoeamwRXZ8vLNQNrHyCyFk/ZD2Bc/Vb6c=` However when I put 'Test:' in a text file and do `./john <file>` It gives me 'No password hashes loaded'.

Is this an issue with how I'm using John The Ripper or am I getting the wrong hashes?

Note: This was a test user and this is not my real password hashed. The encrypted password is 'password'

Comment: The [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186893/os-x-10-9-where-are-password-hashes-stored?rq=1) you mentioned worked fine for me on a Yosemite system - I assume you replaced `<username>` with the correct username for the user in question?

Comment: @mjturner That doesn't work for me. Look at my edit for more info.

Comment: Which version of John the Ripper are you running? Not all versions support 10.7 and later salted SHA-512 hashes... See the [documentation](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/) for more information - you need a **-jumbo** edition.

Comment: @mjturner What do you mean a jumbo edition? Do you have to pay for it? I will tell you my version when I next get a chance.

Comment: The **-jumbo** editions are community-supported editions that add additional features. If you check the [list of downloads](http://www.openwall.com/john/) you will see them listed there. No, you don't have to pay for such releases - they're open source.