# How to get the password hashes for a user in Mac OS X 10.10+, in recovery/single user mode?

Tags: macos, terminal, password, recovery, single-user

I would like to view the hashes on my Mac, in either single user mode, or the terminal in recovery mode.

I tried to follow the steps described in [OS X 10.9: where are password hashes stored](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186893/os-x-10-9-where-are-password-hashes-stored). But I do not see my users plist file in the /var/db... folder, but I see root, nobody, daemon, and other .plist files. How can I find these files in recovery/single user mode?

Note: The OS I would be using is either OS X Yosemite or OS X El Capitan; both would be great to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting to Recovery Mode you will find the users' .plist files in

```
/Volumes/NameOfMainVolume/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/...
```

Don't forget to escape spaces in the name of your main OS X volume with a backslash.

Booting to Single User Mode you have to mount your main volume first:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
```

Answer (score 1):

When booting into recovery mode, the main hard drive is mounted under `/Volumes/NameOfMainVolume/` (usually `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD` or `"/Volumes/Macintosh HD"`). So if you need to access files residing on the main drive, include that part into your access path.