# Check whether macOS host is affected by serious vulnerability that enables access to the root superuser

Tags: macos, security, high-sierra

Is it correct to assume that (prior to applying [Security Update 2017-001](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208315)) a host running macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra, i.e. not High Sierra) is *not* affected by the [serious vulnerability that enables access to the root superuser](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/11/28/macos-high-sierra-bug-admin-access/) if [the following command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186893/os-x-10-9-where-are-password-hashes-stored) returns non-empty `ShadowHashData`?

```
sudo plutil -p /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/root.plist
```

Comment: Would simply trying to log in as root (e.g. `su`) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple's support document on [Security Update 2017-001](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208315) macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and earlier are not affected by the vulnerability:

> Not impacted: macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and earlier

If you want to use terminal to find out if you're running 10.12.6 you may want to use the command

`sw_vers -productVersion`

or refer to the question [How to find out Mac OS X version from Terminal?](https://superuser.com/a/75206) on superuser.